# MVC authentication kendoUI SPA

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, requirejs, single-page-application

I have a single page app built with KendoUI javascript framework from Telerik. The pages are loaded from a client router (samples and docs [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/spa/router)) and javascript modules are added with RequireJS. I added some authentication mechanism based on the WIF Session Authentication Module (SAM) based on this article from Dominick Baier : http://leastprivilege.com/2012/02/09/replacing-asp-net-forms-authentication-with-wif-session-authentication-for-the-better/ It works very similar to the Forms authentication since I am just adding a authentication tag with a form url like this :

```
<authentication mode="None">
  <forms loginUrl="~/#/Public/Accueil" timeout="90" slidingExpiration="true" requireSSL="true" />
</authentication>
```

It works fine under a normal .NET MVC4 scenario, but doesn't quite work as well when in a SPA with javascript routing. The view is displayed when the user is not logged, but the corresponding script is not because nothing happens when I click on "Log in" button.

Does anyone have a clue about what I should do to keep the sync between server and client whenever a redirection on the login page occurs on the server ?

**UPDATE :**

When you use a authentication tag and specify a form url, a 302 response is sent to the client every time a page that needs authorization is called without the auth cookie. The URL to wich the browser is redirected then is the one specified in the web.config under the authentication tag (like in my question it is "***base_url*/#/Public/Acceuil**") and the url requested originaly requested is appended as parameter like this : "***base_url*/#/Public/Acceuil?RETURNURL=Private/Profile**". The browser then make a GET request to this new url and gets a 200 with the login view. That works just fine. The problem is that the client methods are in a separate js file that is normally loaded via the client Kendo Router using RequireJS :

router-config.js :

```
        define([
        'jquery',
        'lib/pubsub'
    ], function ($, pubsub) {

        // Index
        var publicAccueil =
        {
            url: "/Public/Accueil",
            activate: function () {
                var that = this;
                require(['app/Public/Accueil'], function () { renderView(that); });
            },
            html: null
        };

        // MDPOublie
        var publicMDPOublie =
        {
            url: "/Public/MDPOublie",
            activate: function () {
                var that = this;
                require(['app/Public/MDPOublie'], function () { renderView(that); });
            },
            html: null
        }; 
// Profil
var privateProfile =
{
    url: "/Private/Profile",
    activate: function () {
        var that = this;
        require(['app/Private/Profile'], function () { renderView(that); });
    },
    html: null
};
    var renderView = function(view, id, params) {
        $.publish("viewActivated", [ view, id, params ]);
    };

    return {
        publicAccueil: publicAccueil,
        publicMDPOublie: publicMDPOublie,
        privateProfile: privateProfile,
};
});
```

Then, in the router file, the route are registered to call the "activate" fonction defined in the config object "routeConfig.privateProfile" for the route, that's what loads the Accueil.js file located unde "app/Public/".

**router.js :**

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'kendo',
  'app/route-config',
  'app/Code52'
], function ($, kendo, routeConfig, Code52) {

    var router = new kendo.Router({
        routeMissing: function (e) { alert("Route not defined : " + e.url); },
        change: function (e) {

            kendo.destroy("#content");
        }
    });

    //Default route
    router.route("/", function() {
        var cheminUrl = window.location.pathname;

        if (cheminUrl === "/") {
            router.navigate(routeConfig.publicAccueil.url);
        }
    });

router.route(routeConfig.publicAccueil.url, function () { routeConfig.publicAccueil.activate(); });
        router.route(routeConfig.publicMDPOublie.url, function () { routeConfig.publicMDPOublie.activate(); });
    router.route(routeConfig.privateProfile.url, function () { routeConfig.privateProfile.activate(); });

//Rest of code ommited for brievty"
```

The page is then loaded from server first time and cached for subsequent calls. And this is the part that doesn't seem to work. The login view is displayed, but the client router is never hit, so the javascript logic is not loaded.

The private section is defined in the web.config to deny access to anonymous users to every views under the path "**Views/Private**" :

```
<location path="Views/Private">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
    <!--this will restrict anonymous user access -->
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Just as an example, if I hit "Private/Profile" by clicking on a link in my favorites, I'm not connected. So the router loads the client script defined for that page in router-config.js. The the browser gets a 302 an redirects to "Public/Accueil' but the client router is never hit. So the "app/Private/Profile.js" file never gets loaded.

Comment: I think you should add more code and explanations; what kind of redirect are you talking about? What does your view look like and what's the JS code that should be there but isn't?

Comment: I updated my question with as many details I could. Hope it'll be enough for someone to give me a hint. I'll be more than happy to add more stuff if needed.

Comment: maybe I misunderstand the design, but couldn't you set up the router as part of the login page, and then do the SPA routing from there, switching out the login form for other views?

Comment: Well, in RequireJS typical design, you have the "_Layout" view that reference only 2 scripts : "require-jquery.js" itself and one "main.js" containing the requirejs config. That is the one that requires the "router.js" file.

Comment: But I should try and include some login script there maybe... I'll give it a try and let you know.

Comment: yes, I meant including those only, but on the login page instead of the layout; since it's a single page app, you don't need it on every page, because the other pages are loaded via the router? and if the user is not logged in, he's redirected to the start page of the app that lets him log in and go to other pages using the router

Comment: If I try to go to "Private/Documents" for exemple by entering the link in adress bar or clicking a link, the browser will load scripts for this view, but will receive a 302 from the server. This will then redirect to the Public/Accueil, but the client router never gets hit. So no js file loaded

Comment: even if you include main.js on Public/Accueil?